# ldap authentication using ActiveDirectyoryMembershipProvider on GC port fails in MVC2 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, active-directory, activedirectorymembership

I am developing an MVC2 application using C# ASP.NET.

In my application I am using ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider for user authentication. Below is the snippet from my web.config file.

If I use the global catalog port 3268 in my connection string I get the error "LDAP connections on GC port are not supported against Active Directory". I did google on this error message and was unable to find an  appropriate solution. Many people have suggested using port 389, some have suggested code changes. But I want to be able to use the GC port to allow users connected to different forests, because it is more cleaner.

Some observations:

- The same connection string(with port 3268) is working perfectly for other applications in my company i.
- When I change my connection string to point to port 389 it works perfectly i.e people who belong to the local domain are able to log in. However people from another domain cant.
- I put breakpoints in my AcconuntModel and AccountController. With connection string pointing to port 3268,Membership.Provider threw "ConfigurationErrorsException".

It would be very helpful if someone can help me resolve this issue.

web.config:

```
 <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://myADServer.abc.ad:389/DC=abc,DC=ad" /> 

<membership defaultProvider="MyADMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="1000" connectionUsername="ldapuser@abc.ad" connectionPassword="password" connectionProtection="None" enableSearchMethods="True" name="MyADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider,System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider,MySql.Web,Version=6.5.4.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="MySqlMembershipConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" autogenerateschema="true" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <!-- Added for custom provider -->
    <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="DDMS_Custom_RoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add applicationName="/" connectionStringName="ddms_dataEntities2" name="DDMS_Custom_RoleProvider" type="DDMS_sourcecode.Utilities.DDMS_Custom_RoleProvider, DDMS_sourcecode" />
        <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" autogenerateschema="true" name="MySqlRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider,MySql.Web,Version=6.5.4.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Comment: Hi Terry.. I am not able to identify your edit... Can you please let me know what changes you have suggested?

Comment: This issue is still open. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can someone please help me out?

Comment: I am still not able to find a solution for this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If it is Global Catalog that you need to search, why dont you try it this way

```
using (DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("GC://DC=yourdomain,DC=com"))
using (DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot))
{
    ds.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=userID1)";
    ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    using (SearchResultCollection src = ds.FindAll())
    {
        foreach (SearchResult sr in src)
        {
            uxFred.Content = sr.Path;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your response Travis. I am using ActiveDirectory Membership provider to facilitate AD authentication. I dont want to just the search but want to enable authentication using the validate_user method provided by the membership. The same connection string works for so many applications in my company. For some reason, when I use the port 3268, I get the error I have pointed in my question. Other observations I have are that Membership.Providers has the same list of providers irrespective of the changes I make in web.config. I read somewhere that membership is a static class initiated once

Comment: Well the thing is,you cannot authenticate using GC. GC is used to query objects in the forest/domain using ldap protocol, its no way involved in any type of authentication. Kerberos is the protocol used for authentication. Port 3268 is a designated port for LDAP in the Global Catalog Server.Users can also do a limited browse on the Global Catalog database through port 3268.